# SQL Server AG secondary replica database still in Restoring mode

Tags: backup, availability-groups, restore, high-availability, sql-server-2019

I created an AlwaysOn in SQL Server 2019 and I selected the Full Database and Log Backup option. Now it created a database in secondary replica but it is still in Restoring mode. My DB size is 16MB and it is very small just for test. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It is because my account doesn't have sufficient permission.

Comment: And specifically what permissions were needed? I have sysadmin but mine is stuck in a restoring state on one server but it worked on another.